# How to fix Error Has no member "create"

Tags: cocos2d-x

```
bool AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching() {

auto director = Director::getInstance();
auto glview = director->getOpenGLView();
if(!glview) {
    glview = GLView::create("My Game");
    director->setOpenGLView(glview);
}
```

i don't know why my code has this problem   4   IntelliSense: class "cocos2d::GLView" has no member "create". Iam building for windows 32bit.

Comment: Which platform are you trying to run on? And could you please fix the code block in your question. Will make it easier for us to read.

Answer (score 0):

GLView is an abstract base class that is shared by all platforms.

The implementation class is typically called GLViewImpl, but its creation function is still platform specific. So, on iOS, you need to call `GLViewImpl::createWithEAGLView`.

Answer (score 0):

As Chris mentioned GLView is an abstract class. If you're running on Win32 then you should use:

```
GLViewImpl::createWithRect("Window name", Rect(0, 0, designResolutionSize.width, designResolutionSize.height));
```

Let me know if this helps.